# Escaped backslash doubled in object

Tags: javascript, string, object, escaping

I have a string with a backslash in it: `const string = '/\\.txt/` which return the expected result (`/\.txt/`) but if I put this string to an object the escapes backslash is just duplicate itself, so my object returns this: `{ string: '/\\.txt/' }`, even if I declare it with `{ string }` or `{string: string}`.
So, have someone met with this issue before?
And, if yes, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're just not seeing the fact that backslashes need to be escaped in JSON? That *is* JSON output you're looking at, right?

Comment: Can you add some code? It's nearly impossible to understand what you're talking about as it is.

Comment: So, this is my function: 
`() => {
   const string = '/\\.' + 'alma';
   return {string}
` 
And this is what returns the `{ string: '/\\.alma' }` object.

Comment: Right, so that looks to me like an object with a `string` property which contains a single backslash. You're seeing it escaped because you're looking at the JSON representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced it this way:

```
var foo = {
    bar: () => { const string = '/\\.' + 'alma'; return {string}}
};
```

Now

```
JSON.stringify(foo.bar())
```

will yield

> "{"string":"/\.alma"}"

but if I negate the `stringify` with

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo.bar()))
```

then the result will be

> {string: "/.alma"}

so indeed, you are just seeing that the backslash needs to be escaped in JSON.